# Fitting small cubes into a bigger container

Tags: volume

This is a simple question that I have done on a test paper, but the given answer is confusing me.

The question states that a person has a bunch of cubes of volume 3 cubic centimetres. The person also has a container of size 6cm x 6cm x 3cm. What is the maximum number of small cubes that can be fit in the large container? No matter how I try I get 36 cubes, but the answer given is 32. How is this so?

Comment: Hint: if a cube has volume $3$ cubic centimeters, what is the sidelength of the cube?

Comment: The container has a volume of 108 cubic centimeters but you won't be able to fill it up completely.  As Peter Woolfitt says, how long is the side of each small cube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each small cube has a side length of $\sqrt[3]{3}\approx 1.442$ cm.  Two cubes would thus fit in the height ($2\sqrt[3]{3}<3$).  Four cubes would fit in the length ($4\sqrt[3]{3}<6$) and four cubes would fit in the width.  You could thus fit $2\times 4\times 4=32$ small cubes in the container.

Comment: It is assumed that you cannot chop up the small cubes into smaller pieces.

Comment: Now, is it possible to prove that we can't fit more cubes in by allowing the cubes to not be parallel to the sides of the box?

Comment: @JimmyK4542, very good observation!  I don't have time to think about it right now (I have to leave soon) but perhaps someone else can think of a proof.

Comment: @JimmyK4542. This is a very good point since $32$ small cubes occupy $96$ $cm^3$ and so $12$ $cm^3$ are left. I am almost sure that shaking the container will allow to put at least one extra small cube. Now, the problem is to prove it !! Cheers.

Comment: Wow, you guys have blown my mind. I did not realise this method of calculation. Thanks guys! (I'm interested to see @JimmyK4542 's idea in action.)